# Cannot hide Controls in NSView

Tags: cocoa

I am developing  an application in cocoa. Now I am facing a critical issue. I can't hide controls NSButton in NSView. I used the following code

```
[btn setHidden:YES]
```

but this "btn" control is not becoming hidden. I used the following code to check whether the button is hidden

```
[btn isHidden]
```

but this return YES. Also I can't sent a value to NSTextfield while showing this view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try running the runloop once after hiding the button:

```
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on a NSProgressIndicator which refused to hide, instead of 1 second, I used 0.02  which seems to clear it up.  No idea why displayIfNeeded, setNeedsDisplay etc didn't force it.   It hides elsewhere in my app normally without this.

Comment: You can also use `[NSDate distantPast]` to let the runloop run only once.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what else is going on in the application it is hard to know why this would not be making the button hidden.

Are you blocking the main event loop such that the update events are not getting handled? Generally this is not a good thing to do.

One thing you can do to force an immediate update is to call displayIfNeeded on the button or its parent view or window. This should cause the view to be redrawn. This would be suitable as an experiment to validate that the button will draw (or not draw) its correct state. If calling displayIfNeeded does cause it to disappear then you will need to determine why update events are not getting handled correctly.